# How to make multiple phone calls at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-phone-call

I have an application, where I'll be having between 10-100 minimum phone numbers on which i want to periodically (let's say once a week) make a missed call (about 20-40 seconds of ringing and then hanging up, using all numbers "at the same time").
I haven't tried any code yet but i already looked up how to make calls, missed calls etc. so I hope I know my way around this stuff a little bit.
Now you see if I'd do it by using simplest way, I'd have about one hour of my phone making these missed calls one after each other.
 Is there a way to make these calls somehow overlap each other (make them all at the same time)? Because I looked up that I can't make a phone call in background and since we are using activity to start a call, if I immediately start call after previous one, I suppose since it's an activity it's gonna pause.

Comment: You are not asking a question, you're requesting someone to build for you. Probably this site is more appropriate https://freelancer.com

Comment: Well maybe I used the wrong way to ask, but by any means I don't want anyone to make that for me. I haven't seen a single answer to this problem on the internet, so my question is. Is it even possible to do? And if so which resources should I use.

Comment: Assume it's possible, and try tackling the problem by breaking it down into manageable pieces that you can research, test and ask about individually. As it stands, your question is too broad for SO. Requests for external resources are also considered off-topic here.

Comment: It is possible to initiate calls by holding the PHONE_CALL permission (without going through the dialer and the user having to press the call button for each call). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE To have multiple calls, it depends on your network operator services (from my experience in Spain no more that two calls at the same time). I don't know how this is supposed to be implemented.
As @shmosel said, break your question into pieces and ask more specific questions. My answer just gives you some pointers.

Comment: I was already kinda familiar with the initiate phone call part, but nevertheless thanks for clarification. You kinda got me with the operator restrictions, I'll have to check how is it going in here, but it's probably gonna be similar. Now with this in mind and the fact that I can't make call in background, customers are not gonna be pleased heh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible to call different phone numbers simultaneously on Android and mobile operators do not let you do it either. If you really want to do it, you should use an API like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com) to make all calls. However, if you're using the API, your own phone numbers will be used for calls, not the mobile phone owner number.

And if you want to know how to do it all at once, this is what threads are invented for! Assuming you have 100 phone numbers, use 100 threads to simultaneously call and hang them via API.

Comment: I completely forgot about threads, that's a good point. But I didn't know about the operator restrictions. I'll look into it more from these points you made, thanks.